# Write conditional docker properties in Ansible module

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm trying to write conditional properties in the Ansible module `docker_container`. For example adding `log_options` when a var is set. Any idea? Ansible doesn't seem very elastic in this task.

```
name: vault
become: yes
docker_container:
  name: vault
  image: vault
  state: started
  restart: yes
  network_mode: host
  command: server
    capabilities:
      - IPC_LOCK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to read about [omitting parameters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters):

```
docker_container:
  ...
  log_options: "{{ my_log_opts | default(omit) }}"
  ...
```